# How to get the 'value' from javascript object of a json string?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json and then converted it to a javascript object.  I would like to know how I would go about getting the value from the corresponding key.  I think there is an issue with the spaces between my key values.

```
 json = {"John Leipold":"714129198","Adrian Osika":"214102597","cioGmin":"330199393"}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
 var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);

  for(var k in jsonObj){

    console.log('key: ' + k);
    console.log('jsonObj.k: ' + jsonObj.k);

 }
```

I get an 'undefined' value for the value from the key (k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following (using bracket notation):

```
 console.log('jsonObj.k: ' + jsonObj[k]);
```

```js
var json = "{\"John Leipold\":\"714129198\",\"Adrian Osika\":\"214102597\",\"cioGmin\":\"330199393\"}";
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
for(var k in jsonObj){
    console.log('key: ' + k);
    console.log('jsonObj.k: ' + jsonObj[k]);
}
```